# Error 500 : Insertion of data into a data base through a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am a beginner to concepts such as servlets in Java and lately I have been trying my hand at them. I am trying to insert a row in to the customer(customerid, username, password) table where customerid is autogenerated but unfortunately I am always faced with an Error 500. Here is my servlet, my HTML files and the error messages displayed on my console.

**newUserLoginServelet.java**

```
package loginPackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import resources.MyUtil;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class NewUserLoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Here a new/first time user sets up his/her login credentials.", urlPatterns = { "/NewUserLoginServlet" })
public class NewUserLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public NewUserLoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        String SQL = "insert into table customer (username, password) values (" + "'" + username + "','" + password + "');" ;

        Connection connection = MyUtil.getConnection(); /*Import resources.MyUtil */

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        try {
             /*Throws SQLException*/
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeQuery(SQL);
            out.println("New user credentials injected into the database.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to the SG Supermarket.</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to the SG supermarket.</h1>

<a href="signIn.html">In case you are not a new user.</a></br>
<a href="signUp.html">In case you are a new user.</a>
<
/body>
</html>
```

**signUp.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>User sign up (First time user)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="NewUserLoginServlet">
    Please enter the credentials you wish to be.                </br> 
    Username : <input type="text" value="username">         </br>
    Password : <input type="password" value="password">     </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit your credentials.">  </br> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyUtil.java**

```
package resources;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MyUtil {
    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
    private static String password = "*****";
    private static String user = "root";

    public static Connection getConnection()  {
        if (connection == null) {
            try { 
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // ClassNotFoundException
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return (connection);
    }
}
```

**Error message :**

```
Type Exception Report

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    loginPackage.NewUserLoginServlet.doGet(NewUserLoginServlet.java:51)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Is there something wrong with my insertion of data into the DB or if I am failing to create connections between my HTML and servlet? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Screen shot of my DB URL**
[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SGCart2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>    
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
    <description>NewUserLoginServlet</description>
    <display-name>NewUserLoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>NewUserLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>loginPackage.NewUserLoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewUserLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewUserLoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: On your form try adding method="GET"

Comment: @Austin Doesn't work. Wonder what's wrong.

Comment: Did you add the servlet to your web.xml

Comment: No. I was under the impression that web.xml already references to index.html which in turn leads to my servlet.

Comment: Check out this article it does a great job of explaining how to setup setup servlets https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm

Comment: One more thing before that try changing protected void doget to public void doget

Comment: Thanks a ton. @Austin

Comment: share `MyUtil ` class code also

Comment: Posted MyUtil  @Ravi

Comment: Could you validate your mysql database details like url and database name etc ?

Comment: As in? It has been initialized as shown. @Ravi

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of your mysql db with url used for access ?

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty check out my edited answer, i noticed you deleted your comment on my answer. So made your DBConnection class more clear. Let me know if it works  !

Comment: @Ravi I have added the screenshot of my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sql statement is incorrect:

```
String SQL = "insert into table customer (username, password) values (" + "'" + username + "','" + password + "');" ;
```

it should be:

```
String SQL = "insert into customer (username, password) values ('" + username + "','" + password + "');" ;
```

You should also consider doing a preparedstatement instead, it's much simpler and you don't have to mess around with using double+single quotes together like that which can be very confusing if your insert statement is much larger:

```
  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");

try(Connection conn= MyUtil.getConnection()){

              PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into customer (username,password) values (?,?);");  
               pst.setString(1, username);
               pst.setString(2, password);

                pst.executeUpdate();    

          }catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Whenever you insert, update, delete you have to use **.executeUpdate();** and not **.executeQuery();**

Also i recommend looking up the MVC architecture. (Model View Controller)... It's not very good practice to do database commands within a servlet. You're supposed to separate this logic for safety and organization reasons.

The error you got is a nullpointerexeption from line 51 in NewUserLoginServlet. Which means this line is wrong:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
```

remove brackets around this in your DBConnection Class (MyUtil):

```
 return (connection);
```

should be just:

```
 return connection;
```

**EDIT: Try this as your DBConnection class:**

```
 public class MyUtil {
        private static Connection conn = null;
        private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
        public static Connection getConnection()  {
                try { 
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "*****");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return conn;
        }
```

**Edit 2: in your web.xml you should have something like this:**

```
  <servlet>
    <description>NewUserLoginServlet</description>
    <display-name>NewUserLoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>NewUserLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>loginPackage.NewUserLoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewUserLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewUserLoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I did the changes as you have asked me to but I get a blank screen and my DB isn't updated either. I don't get any more errors.

Comment: @abhijeet in your web.xml file, what is your newuserlogin servlet mapped to?

Comment: Nothing really. It starts from index.html @Jonathan

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty check out my second edit. It shows the servlet mapping you should have in web.xml... if you don't have this in web.xml, then it's not surprising you get a blank screen.

Comment: Should it be placed under <welcome-files> or outside?

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty nah, it goes under, but still inbetween <web-app>

If you make a new Servlet, you will see that it gets automatically inserted there... Also you have to restart the server if you make changes to that file, otherwise it won't update.

Comment: Placing it within <welcome-files> returns an error in my .xml file whereas placing it outside causes the server to stop running.

Comment: Again, you're not supposed to put it in <welcome-files>.... That part is only for the jsp/html the user will first view when they go to your site...

If you don't have servlet mapping in that file, then your servlets won't work. It's as simple as that. Remember to restart the server and clean project/ make sure all the information is correct or you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yes I did! @Jonathan

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear. Thanks for giving me the answer. Have a nice day/night :)